# 訪問状況をホバーしたときのツールチップのテキストが翻訳できない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, traducir.win

ユーザーアクティビティの「x日訪問、y日連続」と書かれたテキストをクリックすると、訪問状況のカレンダーが確認できます。さらにこのテキストをホバーすると「Click to view daily visit calendar」という英語のツールチップが表示されます。

そこでこのテキストを翻訳しようと [ja.traducir.win で検索した](https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EClick&translationStatus=2)のですが、当該テキストを見つけることができませんでした。このテキストはまだ string として追加されていないのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ユーザープロフィールのページは少し前にデザインが変更になったので、その影響での追加忘れだと思われます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

当該テキストの string が Transifex に追加されました。[翻訳の入力はこちらの Traducir から可能です。](https://ja.traducir.win/strings/16233)